# Fix Typescript function outside of return

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, filter

I am developing on a NodeJS and Typescript project already created, and there is a function that I do not understand very well how it works and I do not believe that it is very well done.

The function is in charge of comparing two objects and extracting the information found only in the first one, although I don't really know how.

All the logic of the function is inside the return and I would like to know how to get it out and make it in a way that is easier to understand.

This is the function:

```
public async objectComparer(fstArr: any, secArr: any) {

      try {

          return Promise.resolve( (current: any) => {
              return (
                fstArr.filter((secArr: any) => {
                  return secArr.fileName == current.fileName;
                }).length == 0
              );
          });
          
      } catch (error) {
          return Promise.reject(error);
      }
      
    }
```

I pass him two objects:

```
let obj1 = [ 
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.txt' },
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TES.txt' } ];

let obj2 = [ 
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.txt' },
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt' } ];
```

I run the function:

```
let onlyObj1 = obj1.filter(await this.objectComparer(obj2, obj1));
```

And this is what it returns:

```
let objReturn = [ { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TEST.csv' } ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly twisted code. The result in your code would be

```
let objReturn = [ { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TES.csv' } ];
```

not

```
let objReturn = [ { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TEST.csv' } ];
```

(note the last T difference).

From what I can read, it's not clear what the purpose of this code is. Lets assume it's filtering the objects that are present in the first array but not in the second. You could simplify this with these steps:

- Declare a type Country to really use Typescript power:

```
type Country = {
    codCountry: string, fileName: string
}
```

- Remove async/await since you don't need them in this case
- Simplify the object comparer in this way:

```
public presenceInFirstArrayButNotInSecond = (fstArr: Array<Country>, sndArr: Array<Country>) => {
        return fstArr.filter(
            fstElem => sndArr.filter(
                sndElem => sndElem.fileName == fstElem.fileName
            ).length == 0
        );
    }
```

And call it like this:

```
let onlyObj = this.filter(obj1, obj2);
```

That should give you the same result

```
let objReturn = [ { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TES.csv' } ];
```